# How to use HTML5 Entities in Rails 4 Helper Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, tags, helper, entities

I've been trying to use cdata_section, content_tag, escape_once and tag from the tag helper on rails to make the "X" appear from ✖

```
<%= link_to( ("&#x2716;"), url_options = {:base_rate_id => rates.id}, class: "button tiny" ) %
```

no luck with the different methods. it either displays nil or the raw literal "&#x2716"; is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

```
<%= link_to( sanitize("&#x2716;"), url_options = {:base_rate_id => rates.id}, class: "button tiny" ) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to un-escape HTML entities as follow:

```
<%= link_to(CGI.unescapeHTML("&#x2716;"), url_options = {:base_rate_id => rates.id}, class: "button tiny" ) %>
```

P.S.: May be you need to include the CGI library:

```
require 'cgi'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax

```
<%= link_to("&#x2716;".html_safe, url_options = {:base_rate_id => rates.id}, class: "button tiny") %>
```

However you should be careful using `html_safe`. Ensure that no user provided input makes its way into a string rendered using it.